# Как вытащить объект с полем типа Long, который в DB Timestamp?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Работаем с PostgreSQL + Hibernate

вот на всякий случай конфигурационный файл

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/crudv4</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>

        <!-- Mapping files -->
        <mapping class="com.tunix70.crudv4.model.Region"/>
        <mapping class="com.tunix70.crudv4.model.Post"/>
        <mapping class="com.tunix70.crudv4.model.Writer"/>
        <mapping class="com.tunix70.crudv4.model.PostStatus"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

В POJO Post у меня даты created и updated.

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "post", schema = "public")
    public class Post {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "post_id")
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "content")
        private String content;
    //    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "created")
        private Long created;
    //    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
        @Column(name = "updated")
        private Long updated;
        @Column(name = "post_status", columnDefinition = "enum('active', 'deleted')")
        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        private PostStatus postStatus;
```

Имеем метод получения List из DB.

```
public class PostDAOImpl implements PostRepository {
    @Override
    public List<Post> getAll() {
        Session session = null;
        List <Post> postList = null;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().withOptions().
                    jdbcTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")).openSession();
            CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<Post> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Post.class);
            criteriaQuery.from(Post.class);

            postList = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e);
        } finally {
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return postList;
    }
```

и вот какую ошибку выводит:

```
апр. 06, 2021 2:09:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22003
апр. 06, 2021 2:09:08 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: Bad value for type long : 2021-04-06 10:08:05
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute query
```

Comment: Не силён в JPA, но возможно вам поможет добавление transient поля типа Long и конвертировать поле базы данных на него в событиях @PostLoad/@PostUpdate/@PostPersist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функционалом [AttributeConverter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/AttributeConverter.html) и в явном виде преобразовывать Long в Timestamp и обратно:

```java
@Column(name = "created")
@Convert(converter = TimeStampToLongConverter.class)
private Long created;
```

Сам конвертер при этом может выглядеть так (проверки на null опустим для сокращения работающего концепта):

```java
@Converter
public class TimeStampToLongConverter implements AttributeConverter<Long, Timestamp> {
    @Override
    public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(Long meta) {
        return Timestamp.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(meta));
    }

    @Override
    public Long convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp dbData) {
        return dbData.getTime();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать Date вместо Long

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: по заданию нужно обязательно использовать тип Long

Comment: Long должен быть именно в сущности? Нельзя вытащить из базы Date и уже потом преобразовать в Long?

Comment: да, именно в сущности, это все затрудняет