# Spring Boot Data JPA, как добавить логику при чтении объекта из базы?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Всем привет!
Есть **Entity**, в котором есть поле **Integer**. Хотелось бы добавить проверку значения, которое поднимается из БД и некоторую свою логику. Например, если в БД **null** писать в поле **0** (ноль).
Пробовал добавлять сеттер и конструктор с этой логикой, но ничего не получилось, видимо Spring использует Reflection или ещё каку диковину :)
В принципе, можно было бы добавить геттер и отдавать программе значение с подменой, но это поле является ключом для другого, которое ManyToOne, поэтому такой путь не подходит.

Что можно сделать? Предлагает ли Spring какой-то способ решения данной задачи?

Дополню. Ниже предложили вариант с конвертером, но в ответе форматирование скукожилось, поэтому напишу здесь:

Спасибо, конвертер работает, но он преобразует только моё поле. А надо чтобы ещё поднимался из базы связанный объект. У меня сейчас так:

```
@Column(name = "myobj_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) 
@Convert(converter = NullToOneConverter.class) 
private Integer myobjID; 

@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "myobj_id", referencedColumnName = "id") 
private MyObject myObject;
```

т.е. ссылка на колонку, а там null. А можно ли сделать чтобы в качестве ID было моё, уже сконвертированное поле? Прикрутить такой же конвертер к ID Myobject не получилось.

Comment: используйте конвертер https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266844/192901 и реализуйте в нём свою логику.

Comment: @kami, дополнил вопрос

Comment: `т.е. ссылка на колонку, а там null.` - вот тут непонятно. Если null, то связи нет, всё логично. А если связь есть - то почему в базе null? Это выглядит как нарушение целостности

Comment: @kami. В базе именно так. В этом поле может быть значение и тогда эта запись ссылается на другую (где это значение primary key), либо null, тогда ссылки нет. Но мне эту ситуацию надо обработать. Если null - загрузить в связанный объект некую дефолтную запись (с ID = 0). Базу менять не могу, она как данность.

Comment: тогда почему не сделать геттер на `myObject`, который увидев null в поле (либо 0 в myObjID) вернет эту "дефолтную запись", которую вы будете держать где-то отдельно?

Comment: @kami, где-нибудь она уже лежит - в базе. Я знаю её ID и могу её добыть. Но чтобы сделать это на уровне модельного класса мне надо в нём завести ссылку на репозиторий MyObject. Я не знаю правильно ли так делать, но интуитивно - не очень.
Думаю, было бы идеально переопределить метод, которым Spring достаёт myObject. Вот, ищу можно ли так сделать.

Comment: а нельзя один раз вытянуть эту сущность, сделать из неё синглтон (static field) и потом пользоваться ей? Если она не содержит полей, у которых выставлено lazy load, то это может быть выходом.

Answer (score 2):

> **Небольшой дисклеймер:**
> Я не вдавался сильно в логику вашей изначальной задачи и не читал, что Вам написали в комментариях и не могу сказать насколько адекватно данное решение, относительно желаемого поведения.
> Заранее прошу прощения за столь короткий ответ. Если к данному ответу будут комментарии относительно корректности его применения - можете к ним прислушаться.

Но то, что Вы хотите сделать(а именно, добавить собственную логику при загрузке объекта) можно сделать с помощью обработчиков событий жизненного цикла сущности ( `JPA Entity Lifecycle Events` )

У объекта модели есть ряд состояний:

- добавление
- обновление
- удаление
- загрузка

в первых трех состояниях генерируются события "ДО" и "ПОСЛЕ".
В последнем состоянии, по понятным причинам, событие генерируется только после загрузки(до загрузки просто нечего обрабатывать)

Соответственно есть 7 событий модели, которые можно отловить.
Самым простым способ это сделать - проставить одну нижеуказанных аннотаций, над методом модели, который нужно будет вызвать при возникновении данного события

- `@PrePersist` — перед добавлением
- `@PostPersist`  — после добавления
- `@PreUpdate`  — перед обновлением
- `@PostUpdate` — после обновления
- `@PreRemove` — перед удалением
- `@PostRemove` — после удаления
- `@PostLoad` — после загрузки

Соответственно, Вы можете объявить метод необходимой обработки/инициализации объекта и проставить над ним аннотацию `@PostLoad`

```java
@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    // ...
    // тут, наверное будут перечисленны Ваши поля...
    // ...

    // данный метод будет вызван сразу после загрузки из базы данных
    // и до того как объект будет отдан вам
    @PostLoad
    public void myAwesomePostLoadHandler() {
        // ...
        // тут будет логика обработки или инициализации 
        // Вашего объекта после загрузки из БД
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я пробовал через @PostLoad, но проблема в том что мне надо было не только поменять "обычное" поле, но и поле-объект, которое надо было поднять из БД. А значит в модельном классе мне была бы нужна ссылка на репозиторий что как бы совсем неправильно, да и не работает такой вайринг. Как решил - написал ниже.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, решил добавлением дополнительного сервисного класса, который берёт объекты из репозитория и преобразует как надо, а основная программа уже получает готовые объекты из него. Что есть правильно ибо преобразование - это уже бизнес-логика и не надо её мешать с DAO. Самое смищное что это и есть Спринг-Путь и это описано во всех учебниках. А я чёт затупил :) Ну, ничего: понимание ведёт к запоминанию, в следующий раз буду умнее :)